# What is causing "UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library" using libGDX on Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, libgdx

For a school project me and my team want to develop a game using libGDX in Java. So we set up the project with maven. The set up already included some basic code to which displays the libGDX logo on a black background.
So to see whether everything works my team and I build the project with `mvn -Pdesktop package` then we executed the jar file in the target folder with `java -jar filename.jar`
The problem now is that this worked for everybody except me and I'm suggesting that has to with the OS because I'm the only one in the team using Linux (The others have Windows and MAC OS).

The complete Terminal output I get is:

```
thyrexx@thyrexx-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-3:~/ProgrammingProjects/Java/dieter/desktop/target$ java -jar dieter-desktop-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /tmp/libgdxthyrexx/7b43be9b/liblwjgl.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio.OpenALAudio.<init>(OpenALAudio.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:82)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:64)
    at de.dieter.java.DieterDesktop.main(DieterDesktop.java:11)
```

Dieter is the Project name.

Would be very happy if anyone has an idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: *Can't load library: /tmp/libgdxthyrexx/7b43be9b/liblwjgl.so* Is that file present?

Comment: @g00se, actually not exactly. In this directory are two files: "liblwjgl64.so" and "libopenal64.so"

Comment: Try going in there and doing `cp liblwjgl64.so liblwjgl.so` then try again

Comment: Then I get the following:
`UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libgdxthyrexx/7b43be9b/liblwjgl.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/lib/libjawt.so: version \`SUNWprivate_1.1' not found (required by /tmp/libgdxthyrexx/7b43be9b/liblwjgl.so)`

Comment: I think you're going to have to reinstall libGDX - it looks broken. Maybe you were circumspect and used the /tmp directory but that could cause problems. I would follow the documentation